# pushing element is changing previous elements in json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, loops

I have two json array.
exp:

```
 $scope.arr1 = [
            { "id": 1, "first_name": "Philip", "last_name": "Kim", "email": "pkim0@mediafire.com", "country": "Indonesia", "ip_address": "29.107.35.8" },
            { "id": 2, "first_name": "Judith", "last_name": "Austin", "email": "jaustin1@mapquest.com", "country": "China", "ip_address": "173.65.94.30" },
            { "id": 3, "first_name": "Julie", "last_name": "Wells", "email": "jwells2@illinois.edu", "country": "Finland", "ip_address": "9.100.80.145" },
            { "id": 4, "first_name": "Gloria", "last_name": "Greene", "email": "ggreene3@blogs.com", "country": "Indonesia", "ip_address": "69.115.85.157" },
            { "id": 5, "first_name": "Andrea", "last_name": "Greene", "email": "agreene4@fda.gov", "country": "Russia", "ip_address": "128.72.13.52" }]

$scope.arr2=[];
```

and I want to push elements of arr1 to arr2 field by field according to some condition.

```
var object;
var temp = {};

  for (var i in $scope.arr1) {
    object = $scope.arr1[i];
       for (var property in object) {

            temp2 = object.id + '_' + property;
            if ($scope.someOtherData.indexOf("unhighlighted") != -1) {
               temp[property] = "";

              }
             else {

               temp[property] = object[property];

             }
          }
        $scope.arr2.push(temp);
      }
```

MY first question :
First push temp to arr2 OK. But When i push second or more all elements in arr2 turns to last temp values.how can i fix this ?

My second question is: I did not add $$hashKey attribute to arr1. but it is occurs spontaneously. 
How can i prevent this ?

Comment: $$hashKey is private angular variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because in JavaScript the `objects are passed around by reference`. So explaining your code, `temp` is declared globally to the loops, so a object is created and in the loop you assign some value and push the temp to array, all works fine the first time, Now you update the temp to new values in second loop, Here you are updating the `same object` and the object you have pushed into the array is also the same object, you are just dealing with its reference here in the loop till the end, So that's the reason you get the same values in the array and the values being of the last loop. You have basically pushed the same objects multiple times into the array, and updating one will affect all as it all points to the same object.

So here is the fix,

1) as people have already suggested, create a new object in every loop. That way in each loop you create a new object and there is no reference issues. The code would be

```
   for (var i in $scope.arr1) {
    object = $scope.arr1[i];
    var temp = {};  // creating new object in every loop
    for (var property in object) {
      //your stuff
```

2) Just before you push the object into the array make a clone of it and then push, this way you are pushing new objects all the time. The code would be like below.

```
 var newObject = Object.clone(temp); // create a new object by cloning
   $scope.arr2.push(newObject );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a new object for each iteration, then you won't update the same object by reference.

Now you are adding the same object few times to array2 and it's really the same, so in the end you will have in array 2 few copies of the same object.

```
//this help you to prevent usage of the same object
var temp = {};
for (var property in object) {
     //please add here to not copy something that you don't
     if(object.hasOwnProperty(property))
     {         
        ... 
     }
```

Comment: the var need to be declared before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the var temp before for loop:

```
for (var i in $scope.arr1) {
   object = $scope.arr1[i];
   var temp = {};  //<--------here
   for (var property in object) {
```